# Is there any solution for - Packet for query is too large (4,739,923 > 65,535) for mysql has greater than 1gb

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, mysql-connector

I developed spring boot, jpa with mysql database and try to connect with remote server database, when I try to access an api, throwing a MYSQL error like '***Packet for query is too large (4,739,923 > 65,535). You can change this value on the server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable***'. I increased the max_allowed_packet size to 5gb and when I check in db using '***show variable name like 'max_allowed_packet***' showing 5gb but when try to connect database through application throwing error.

As per mysql doc, the max_allowed_packet limit should be 1gb but in my case I need that 5gb.
so increasing the max_allowed_stack won't work.

Is there any solution for the same. Is there any flag/config to ignore the max_allowed_packet functionality ?

It's failing during deployment also, the error full stack trace is below,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at com.ptdsapi.main.PtdsapiApplication.main(PtdsapiApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:387) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (4,739,923 > 65,535). You can change this value on the server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:107) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
... 36 common frames omitted
```

and pom.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.ptdsapi</groupId>
<artifactId>ptdsapi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>ptdsapi</name>
<description>PTDSAPI application</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <!--<version>5.1.45</version> -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <source>8</source>
    <target>8</target>
    <release>8</release>
</configuration>
```

UserInfo JPA entity,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_info")
public class UserInfo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(name="user_name")
private String name;

@Column(name="user_address")
private String address;

@Column(name="user_phone")
private String phone;

@Column(name="user_email")
private String email;

@Column(name="user_permit_no")
private String permitNo;

@Column(name="user_amount")
private BigDecimal amount;

@Column(name="file_name")
private String fileName;
}
```

Comment: You can't set `max_allowed_packet` to 5GB. You can try, but it will truncate the value to 1GB.

Comment: There is no option to ignore `max_allowed_packet`, but some data types can be split up into multiple packets. What data are you trying to send that requires 5GB?

Comment: @BillKarwin Many projects using the same mysql instance only the database differs so don't know about other projects what kind of data they can send . But in my project just  storing the varchar data not much. you told to split data type into packets right ? how can we do that?

Comment: Without a concrete case I cannot advise.

Comment: @BillKarwin if we create two mysql instances it should work I guess, one with the existing and one we need to create and use that for the current project.

Comment: If you have other users who might try inadvisable things like storing 5GB in a single column, then I guess isolating them into their own instance is a good way to contain the damage.

Comment: Ok @BillKarwin Is there any other possible cause for 5gb issue I mean any configuration or version mismatch between connector and mysql server version ? other than mentioned above cuase, anything else is cuasing this ?

Comment: It sounds like the query is larger than the max packet size. But you haven't shown any query. Is it possible it is a generated query that has become too long? For example, I have seen it happen that a query is generated with an `IN()` list with millions of values, and the query itself is too long to be sent in a packet. That's just an example. It's up to you to figure out which query is causing the error. I can't guess.

Comment: @BillKarwin added full stack trace..during deployment also it's failing..query is simple just update one record in the db, that doesn't have blob column

Comment: All the JPA stuff is meaningless to me, I'm not a Spring or JPA developer. I don't see a specific SQL query, so I have no idea what the solution is. If you search for "Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution" on Stack Overflow, you find many people asking about that exception. It seems to be a generic message that has almost no relevance to the underlying problem, so there could be numerous different solutions.